# Node.js error getting metadata from pdf using exiftool

Tags: node.js, pdf, metadata

I have written one javascript "meta.js" to get metadata from pdf file.

Below is my program,

```
    var exif = require('exiftool');
var fs   = require('fs');

fs.readFile('Sample.pdf', function (err, data) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  else {
    exif.metadata(data, function (err, metadata) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      else
        console.log(metadata);
    });
  }
});
```

When I do "node meta.js" getting below error,

C:\Users\abhishek.suthar\Downloads\node application>node meta.js

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:690:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:709:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
    at Object.exports.metadata (C:\Users\abhishek.suthar\Downloads\node application\node_modules\exiftool\lib\exiftool.js:73:14)
    at C:\Users\abhishek.suthar\Downloads\node application\meta.js:8:10
    at fs.js:334:14
```

I have installed required modules as you can see in my error log paths.

Answer (score -1):

I bet you dont get data, because of the wrong path.
Try:

```
var exif = require('exiftool');
var fs   = require('fs');

fs.readFile('Sample.pdf', function (err, data) {
  console.log("Received data: " + data)

  if (err)
    throw err;
  else {
    exif.metadata(data, function (err, metadata) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      else
        console.log(metadata);
    });
  }
});
```

The way I get correct path:

```
const path = require('path')

path.join(__dirname, "./someFile.pdf")
```

Another approach to check the path is to execute [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback).

And allow me, to give one advice:
Do not hesitate using sync variants of the methods, as far as async approach is not necessary. Why make things compilcated. See: [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) and [fs.statSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path).

Comment: I am getting full data....full pdf file printed in console.I am using 0.12.7 node version.

Comment: Well, I can suggest only going through the issues of the github repo. The starter example looks exactly the same as yours.